# HTML5 Audio in JavaScript: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to create an HTML 5 audio tag in Javascript. I'm having trouble getting it to work and to preload:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

var source1 = document.createElement('source');
source1.type= 'audio/ogg';
source1.src= 'assets/audio/ost.ogg';
source1.setAttribute("preload","auto");
audioElement.appendChild(source1);

var source2 = document.createElement('source');
source2.type= 'audio/mpeg';
source2.src= 'assets/audio/ost.mp3';
source2.setAttribute("preload","auto");
audioElement.appendChild(source2);

audioElement.preload = auto;
audioElement.load();
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here's what I ended up doing for anyone wondering. Works in FF3.6, ff4, safari 5, ie9, chrome 11, opera 11.11 (pc)

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
audioElement.autobuffer = true;

var source1 = document.createElement('source');
source1.type= 'audio/ogg';
source1.src= 'assets/audio/ost.ogg';
audioElement.appendChild(source1);

var source2 = document.createElement('source');
source2.type= 'audio/mpeg';
source2.src= 'assets/audio/ost.mp3';
audioElement.appendChild(source2);
```

And then:

```
audioElement.load();
```

Thanks for your help, Kevin.

Answer (score 2):

`<source>` elements can't have the attribute `preload` and you forgot to put quotes around the preload property on your audio object.

So, remove the `setAttribute('preload', 'auto')` from your `sourceX` objects and put quotes around the `preload` attribute, like so:

```
audioElement.preload = 'auto';
```

- [MDC Audio element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio)
- [MDC Source element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/source)

Comment: @Yahreen I'm not sure if 3.6 has support for preloading.